# undefined value if no result returned in API Mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, undefined

I'm working on my first API every and first time every using Node.js.

I have this code which is test code.  I'm trying to get a Chemist users name and password from my system.
If the query runs and a row exists, this works fine, however I'm try to get a console log error or even a status result and I can't.

It just dies on the const section because there IS no row.

I have tried moving the declarations under the IF section but that also results in errors!

Thanks for any point in the right direction.

```
 const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var config = require('./../../databaseConfig');
var connection= config.connection;


router.get('/:id',(req,res) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblChemists WHERE chemistID = ?',[req.params.id],(err,rows,fields)=>{
               
        const chemName = rows[0].chemistName;
        const chemPass = rows[0].chemistpass;
        
        if(!err)
        console.log(chemName),
        console.log(chemPass),
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Chemist Found',
            name: chemName,
            pass: chemPass  
            
        });
        else
        console.log(err);
    })
    
    
});





module.exports = router;
```

Comment: add some try catch around the rows, OR prior to the const do something like ... if(rows && Array.isArray(rows) && rows.length)...else res.status(500).send('no rows returned')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check to see if rows has data before trying to access it. You should also look at wrapping everything in a try-catch

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM tblChemists WHERE chemistID = ?', [req.params.id], (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (rows && Array.isArray(rows) && rows.length) {
      const chemName = rows[0].chemistName
      const chemPass = rows[0].chemistpass
    } else {
      return res.status(500).send('no rows returned')
    }

    if (!err) {
      console.log(chemName),
      console.log(chemPass),
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Chemist Found',
        name: chemName,
        pass: chemPass

      })
    } else {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks mate, exactly what i was expecting I just am so noob with this that I didnt get there.
I was initially thinking that the (!err) would pick up a non-array error but of course it doesnt.  Thanks again!